# SQL update, how to insert table2 value to table1

Tags: sql, join, db2-400

Let's say table1 as a, table2 as b they both in different structure, but there are same field called branch, I want to insert `table2.branch` to `table1.branch`.

I already tried this:

```
update a                                  
set a.branch = b.branch                   
from table1 a                              
inner join table2 b                        
on a.table1id = b.table2id                    
where (b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3')  
and b.branch <> a.branch
```

Err Msg "Column qualifier or table B undefined."

and this

```
update table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id
set a.branch = b.branch
where a.something <> b.something
```

it's pop up `column b not specified`

I have tried both, but none can do. Does anyone have suggestions how to SQL update this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by : `it's pop up "column b not specified"`

Comment: the message error is that

Comment: Have you tried the script I provided below?

Comment: still column b undefined.

Comment: what SQL are you using? Oracle? Ms Sql? Posgre? My Sql?

Comment: @ray , there is no column `b` though. Could you please update your question with your exact script and error message.

Comment: i don't know for sure. but this sql is in IBM AS/400.

Comment: @PKirby i already edit above, script and error

Answer (score 1):

DB2 for i follows the SQL Standards which do not allow for joined updates.  Take a look at the [reference manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzintro.htm) for the supported syntax of `UPDATE`

This will work on most version of DB2 for i

```
update table1 a                                  
set a.branch = (select b.branch
                from table2 b
                where a.table1id = b.table2id
                  and b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3'                   
               )
```

However, the above will update every row of table1 with the corresponding value from table2.  If a row doesn't exist in table2, it will attempt to update a.branch with NULL.  If a.branch is not null capable, you'll get an error.  Two ways around that.

Update table1 with it's current value

```
update table1 a                                  
set a.branch = coalesce((select b.branch
                from table2 b
                where a.table1id = b.table2id
                  and b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3'                   
               ), a.branch)
```

Or only update the rows in table1 that have a match in table2

```
update table1 a                                  
set a.branch = (select b.branch
                from table2 b
                where a.table1id = b.table2id
                  and b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3'                   
               )
where exists (select * 
                from table2 b
               where a.table1id = b.table2id
                 and b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3'                   
             )
```

If you're on a supported version of DB2 for i, you can make use of the newer MERGE statement.

```
merge into table1 t
using (select a.table1id, b.branch
         from table1 a                              
           inner join table2 b                        
            on a.table1id = b.table2id                    
         where (b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3')  
           and b.branch <> a.branch 
       ) as M
 on t.table1id = m.table1id
when matched
  then update set t.branch = m.branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following :

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.branch = b.branch
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.something <> b.something
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update table1 set branch = b.branch                   
from table1 a                              
inner join table2 b                        
on a.table1id = b.table2id                    
where (b.asd = '1' or b.asd = '3')  
and b.branch <> a.branch
```

The table object needs to be updated should not use aliases

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger, so when table2.branch is inserted it gets automatically added to  table1.branch

Hope this helps